# Academic interviews/surveys about code reviews?

Tags: discussion

I am conducting several academic studies on how developers perform code reviews. The studies involve interviews and/or surveys. Would it be appropriate to post a link to a survey form/interview registration form at codereview.stackexchange.com or codereview.meta.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 7):

## No

Code Review Stack Exchange is a place for performing code reviews, not a place for discussing how to code review.

I would also class first time posters asking for our data on Code Review's Meta as spam. I would not want random people coming here with surveys to be the norm.

<sub>Converted comments to an answer.</sub>